# Parameterized query with several optional search terms

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, optional-parameters

I have a web application with lots of data, and a search/filter function with several fields, such as name, status, date, and so on. I have been using parameterized queries like this for the regular (non-search) queries:

```
$id = $_POST['itemID'];
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE ID = ?";
$stmt_query = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql_query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_params($stmt_query, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt_query);

//and so on..
```

How would I protect agains SQL-injection with multiple, optional parameters? There can be up to 10 separate parameters that might or might not be set.

**Edit as the question seems unclear**:

My example was with one parameter, which is not optional. I know this protects against sql-injection. How would I go about doing this with 10 parameters, where one or several could be set at the same time? E.g. a query such as this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_data 
WHERE NAME = ? 
AND STATUS = ? 
AND DATE = ? 
AND PARAM4 = ? 
AND PARAM5 = ?
```

where the user only wants to search on name and date. How would I do the binding? It's not a good idea to check for each of the 100 possible combinations of search terms.

Comment: you're using bound parameters on prepared statements, so you are automatically protected from sql injection.  SQL injection only presents itself when you're building queries up as a string using unchecked (non-escaped) content derived from user submissions.  bound parameters are automatically escaped by the database driver, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @Lee, nope, he is not. In this particular case ha HAVE to worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already protected against sql injection, as you are using the mysqli_stmt_bind_params which will escape properly for you.

Edit.
You could switch to some database framework to have a clean and beautiful code.

Otherwise... this is so old spaghetti style... but I love it :D

It's quite easy to expand your code to work with an unknown number of parameters. You should just loop on your parameters and at the same time 1. build your query string with the question mark notation, and add your parameters to an array, which you will be passing to maxdb_stmt_bind_param ( resource $stmt , string $types , array &$var ).

So it would look like this. It assumes at least ONE parameter is there (but it's trivial to avoid this).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_data WHERE ";
$and = '';
$types = '';
$parameters = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
  // check that $k is on your whitelist, if not, skip to the next item
  $sql .= "$and $k = ?";
  $and = " AND ";
  $parameters[] = $v;
  $types .= 's';
}
$stmt_query = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_params($stmt_query, $types, $parameters);
```

Comment: @Palantir Thanks, I know that works, but I'm after a way of using it with 10 different params, which might or might not be set. See the edited question for more info.

Comment: Thanks, this tasty pasta dish helps immensely...=P (My entire code base is 'old spaghetti style' for this project - I need to update myself some...=)

Comment: Well you have just added an SQL injection :-P

Comment: @Lizzan throw in a whitelist of allowed field names, or you'll be in trouble

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: how could you do injection here? I have explicitly stated that a whitelist of the allowed columns is absolutely needed (see comment, it's out of the scope of the answer to show how to do it and it's trivial), and the mysqli_stmt_bind_params will take care of escaping. I don't see any injection possibilities...

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Yep, I'm whitelisting. I have some fields that needs to be handled differently anyways, so I'm looping through the fields that can be searched on instead of the $_POST.

Comment: @Palantir, just got a version of this done and it works perfectly. Had to use `call_user_func_array` for the binding, but would never even have known to look for something like it without this. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend switching to PDO. It's built into PHP like the mysqli extension, but has a cleaner syntax and allows you to pass in your parameter values as an array, which you can easily construct dynamically with as many elements as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into PDO. Does it automatically AND whatever parameters are sent in or can you specify it?

Comment: You still write the ? in your query string. It does not build the query for you.

Comment: Ah, OK, then I don't see how it helps me, since I'd still need the 100 different query permutations.

Comment: PDO helps by allowing him to build an array of values to bind at the same time he builds the query string itself. With mysqli, you bind multiple parameters as multiple arguments to a single function call, which requires some messier code to do when you don't know the arguments you'll pass in advance.